# Boolean search text file in Python

Tags: python

I have a text file with 32 articles. Each article starts with the expression: `<Number> of 32 DOCUMENTS`, for example: `1 of 32 DOCUMENTS`, `2 of 32 DOCUMENTS`, etc. In order to find each article I have used the following code:

```
import re 
sections = [] 
current = []
with open("Aberdeen2005.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(r"(?i)\d+ of \d+ DOCUMENTS", line):        
           sections.append("".join(current))
           current = [line]
        else:
           current.append(line)

print(len(sections))
```

So now, articles are represented by the expression `sections`

The next thing I want to do, is to subgroup the articles in 2 groups. Those articles containing the words: economy OR economic AND uncertainty OR uncertain AND tax OR policy, identify them with the number 1.

Whereas those articles containing the following words: economy OR economic AND uncertain OR uncertainty AND regulation OR spending, identify them with the number 2. This is what I have tried so far:

```
for i in range(len(sections)):
group1 = re.search(r"+[economic|economy].+[uncertainty|uncertain].+[tax|policy]", , sections[i])
group2 = re.search(r"+[economic|economy].+[uncertainty|uncertain].+[regulation|spending]", , sections[i])
```

Nevertheless, it does not seem to work. Any ideas why?

Comment: Describe what the expected output of "identify them with the number 'x'" looks like to you.

Comment: well, creating a a group with all the articles that fulfilled certain criteria: for example group1 = sections[1,3,7,9] and group2 = sections[2,4,10,27].

Comment: Okay, I was think more a dictionary `{"1": [1,3,7,9], "2": [2,4,10,27]}`

Comment: either works, as I said I am new to this and I do  not know which one might be more straight forward :)

Comment: Well, you've laid out your logic pretty simply. Python allows for `and` and `or` statements and it seems you know how to use `re.search`, so give it a try and update your question with any problems

Comment: any ideas why my attempt might not be working? Cheers,

Comment: Because you are literally searching for the string `" (economic or economy) and (uncertainty or uncertain) and (tax or policy)"` in your section. You need to do something like `re.search('economy', section) or re.search('policy', section)` where the `or` is a python operand, not me telling you do one or the other

Comment: @cricket_007 you're wrong as well; the pattern that Anders had at that point did search for literal `" economic or economy and uncertainty or uncertain and tax or policy"`, not including any parentheses.

Comment: @AndresAzqueta you should read the [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) and try the regular expressions on texts using [regex101](https://regex101.com/). The latter regular expression does not even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit wordy, but you can get away without using regular expressions here, for example:

```
# Take a lowercase copy for comparisons
s = sections[i].lower()
if (('economic' in s or 'economy' in s) and
    ('uncertainty' in s or 'uncertain' in s) and
    ('tax' in s or 'policy' in s)):
    do_stuff()
```

Comment: this does not consider word boundaries at all

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Correct.

Comment: what do you mean it does not consider word boundaries at all?

Comment: @AndresAzqueta This solution would match not only if the section contains "tax", but also, for example, "ataxia". In other words, it's not matching whole words, but just checking to make sure those particular sequences of characters exist *somewhere* in the section. If that's an important distinction for you, you'll need to look further at regexes.

Comment: great, thanks for the tip. I will check regex and implement a few changes to deal with the problem. Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to write this as a single regular expression, but it is a bit tricky. For each `and` you'd use a zero-width lookahead assertion `(?= )`, and for each `or` you'd use a branch. Also, we'd have to use the `\b` for a word boundary. We'd use `re.match` instead of `re.search`.

```
belongs_to_group1 = bool(re.match(
     r'(?=.*\b(?:economic|economy)\b)'
     r'(?=.*\b(?:uncertain|uncertainty)\b)'
     r'(?=.*\b(?:tax|policy)\b)', text, re.I))
```

Thus not very readable.

A more fruitful approach would be to find all words and put them into a set

```
words = set(re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower()))
belongs_to_group1 = (('uncertainty' in words or 'uncertain' in words)
    and ('economic' in words or 'economy' in words)
    and ('tax' in words or 'policy' in words))
```

Comment: Could you shorten-up `uncertain|uncertainty` to `uncertain(?:ty)?`? And `economic|economy` to `econom(?:ic|y)`

Comment: I did, but I reverted that because it made it even less readable

Answer (score -1):

You can use re.search to find those words. Then you can use if statements and python's `and` and `or` statements for the logic, and then store group one and two as two lists with the section index number as a value.

One thing you might want to note is that your logic may need brackets.

By

economy OR economic AND uncertainty OR uncertain AND tax OR policy

I assume you mean

(economy OR economic) AND (uncertainty OR uncertain) AND (tax OR policy)

which is different to (for example)

economy OR (economic AND uncertainty) OR (uncertain AND tax) OR policy

EDIT1: 
Python will evaluate your statement without brackets from left to right, i.e.:

( ( ( ( (economy OR economic) AND uncertainty) OR uncertain) AND tax) OR policy)

Which I imagine is not what you want (e.g. the above evaluates true if it includes the word policy but none of the others)

EDIT2:
As pointed out in comments, EDIT1 is incorrect, although you would still need brackets to achieve case 1, if you don't have them you will get case 2 instead (and case 3 is a load of rubbish)

Comment: Python absolutely will **not** evaluate `and` and `or` left to right like that. Instead `and`s are always evaluated **first**, and  `or`s afterwards

Comment: @antti Huh, thats interesting. I'd assumed it would evaluated like one would mathematically. Does `and` being evaluated first mean that "economy OR economic AND uncertainty OR uncertain" becomes " economy OR (economic AND uncertainty) OR uncertain" or does it becomes  " (economy OR economic) AND (uncertainty OR uncertain)"

Comment: @user3088440 `and` has higher precedence than `or`, in Python, most other languages, and [in math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Order_of_precedence).

Comment: @user3088440: It becomes your first case. Without any brackets, and's come before or's. This IS mathematically, by the way, as multiplication/division comes before addition/subtraction.

Comment: Huh, had no idea, I've just always bracketed anything ambiguous. Good to know!